# How to connect from Ubuntu VM on Azure to another without uploading the private key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash, private-key, local

**My Topology**

Two Ubuntu servers, the edge which is exposed to the internet, and the core which is only connected locally. Both are on the same subnet and the core only accepts SSH from the edge server. SSH Private keys are stored on my local computer I'm connecting from. I'm using a custom ssh port and MFA on both servers

**What I want to achieve is** to connect from my computer to the edge server via SSH and from there connect to the core server using the private SSH key stored locally.

I'm sure it is quite simple but I have no clue how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is "creating bastion host".
And it can be done by using [ssh-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257968/how-to-forward-local-keypair-in-a-ssh-session).

Comment: I've been looking for something similar. Thank you for pointing it out.
I also found this blog [link](https://www.strongdm.com/blog/ssh-bastion-with-key) which explains it very well.